# "No results " not working on filter search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I'm trying to make a filter search bar, and it works, but the "no results" page isn't. I've tried making the "no results" show up, but whatever I do, it doesn't. (jquery/javascript) Thanks so much for the help! Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div align="right"class="live-search-bar">
 <input class="search-bar" id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search for a game..">
</div>

<div id="button-container">

<div>
  <button class="games-button">Oranges</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="games-button">Bananas</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="games-button">Apples</button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchbar").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#button-container button").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)

      // No Results, Not working

       $('.noresults').remove();
       $("#button-container").each(function () {
                if ($(this).children(':visible').length == 0) 
                    $(this).append('<em>No Results</em>');
      });   
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Adding `tr` into `div` is not the way to go. Just start from the `em` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ryuvd70/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.noresults').hide();
  
  $("#searchbar").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#button-container button").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      $('.noresults').hide();
      
      var noResult = true;
      $("#button-container").children('div').each(function () {
       if ($(this).children(':visible').length != 0) {
         noResult = false;
        }
      });   
      if (noResult) {
       $('.noresults').show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="right"class="live-search-bar">
 <input class="search-bar" id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search for a game..">
</div>

<div id="button-container">
  <div>
    <button class="games-button">Oranges</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="games-button">Bananas</button>
  </div>
  <div>
  <button class="games-button">Apples</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="noresults">
  No Results
</div>
```

You need to loop through each `div` with `button-container`

```
$("#button-container").children('div').each(function () {});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you, I realized now what I did wrong.